# Is there a fast way to modify all the elements of a vector by given value?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, vector, implementation

Basically the title. Is there a relatively fast way to modify all, or a bunch of elements of a vector by a given value, for eg. 1? If not, is there some other datatype that would perform this kind of an operation better?

I have implemented a for loop that basically adds 1 to every element of a vector. Is there some cleaner/shorter way to go about this?

```
vector<int> vct;
for (int i = 0;i<10;i++){
    vct.push_back(i);
}
for (int i = 0;i<vct.size();i++){
    vct[i]++;
}
```

Comment: You could unroll the loop a bit to reduce the loop-overhead.

Comment: To modify every element is an O(N) operation.  You can't get better then that without threading or SIMD

Comment: You could try `std::for_each` which has a multithreaded overload, but it probably won't help much for such a trivial example.

Comment: You could use a range-for loop instead, `for (auto& x : vct) { x++; }`.  Or `std::transform`.

Comment: You could avoid calling `vct.size()` over and over again.

Comment: X/Y problem.  Most likely you are assuming that you need to do this when you don't.  The problem you're really trying to solve probably has answers here that show you how to solve it.

Comment: @NathanOliver; even with  threading or SIMD you only gain a constant factor, so it still stays O(N).

Comment: Is your underlying type always numeric? Maybe you want `std::valarray` rather than `std::vector`...

Comment: Looks like micro-optimization

Comment: @MrSmith42 Trying to optimizing by removing vct.size() without measuring is meaningless. The compiler might already have removed it.

Comment: Fastest is always not to do something. WARNING: Finding a way to solve whatever the actual problem is without incrementing all elements of a container may take thinking.

Comment: Of cause whatever you try to optimize your code you **ALWAYS** need to profile / measure if you really gained something or even made things worse.

Comment: Chances are that this code is already memory-bottlenecked.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is to use a data structure which combines a scalar offset, *base*, and a vector of numbers, *data*. The value of element *i* is then computed as *base*+*data[i]*, which is still O(1). (On modern CPUs, you probably won't notice the time taken by the addition.)

To increment an individual element, you simply increment the particular value in *data*. To increment all elements, you can increment *base*.

If you need to set element *i* to a specific value *v*, you can use *data[i]* = *v* - *base*. But normally this data structure is used for problems where the data is always incremented (or decremented), either individually or collectively, and it is desired to make collective increments O(1).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check if the compiler does not already optimize it. Run the compiler with optimization on (`-O3` on clang and g++ for example) and check the assembly code code.

Clang for example does some optimizations on vectors already, and without meassuring, you will not know if your code will be slower or faster.
https://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html

So make sure to *measure* if you want to know if your optimizations have effect.

My *syntax* favorite is like a commenter above

```cpp
for (auto &x: vec) {
    x .. something
}
```